# URL mapeada no permite que ajax encuentre el recurso

Tags: php, mvc, apache, .htaccess

Ayuda, tengo una estructura de archivos en mvc para php, y todo lo que se escriba en la url pasa por la carpeta public/index.php. el cual accede a la carpeta app/iniciador.php el cual carga las clases con las vistas, controladores y modelos.

el problema es que al usar ajax no me encuentra la url solicitada supongo que es por el mapeo de que hago en el archivo .htaccess este es mi codigo

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options -Multiviews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /norbeV1/public
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

codigo de peticion en js:

```
$(".FormularioAjax").on("submit",function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   var form=$(this);
   var tipo=form.attr("data-form");
   var metodo=form.attr("method");
   var formuData={"usuarioCedula":"010518278"};
   formuData=JSON.stringify(formuData);
   $.ajax({
        type:metodo,
        url:"http://localhost/norbeV1/app/ajax/administradorAjax.php",
        data:{"datos":formuData},
        error:function(jqXHR){
              console.log(jqXHR);},
        success:function(data,textStatus,jqXHR){
            respuesta.html(data+"/"+textStatus);
        }
   });
}
```

y este es el que recibe:

```
<?php
$data=json_decode($_POST["datos"]);
print_r($data);
```

Comment: Intenta agregar `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(?:css|js|jpe?g|gif|png)$ [NC]` y cambiar la ultima por esta `RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9\-\_\/]*)$ index.php?p=$1 [L,QSA]`

Comment: gracias por tu pronta respuesta, podrias explicarme mas en detalle que hacen cada linea

Comment: La primera es la directiva RewriteCond define las condiciones bajo las cuales debe tener lugar la reescritura. La segunda se asegura de que tu url sea limpia y con caracteres validos dentro de los establecidos en la expresion `([a-zA-Z0-9\-\_\/]*)` la parte `[L,QSA]` admite el `querystring`de toda la vida o lo que se traduce a variables por `GET`

Comment: Albert Hidalgo, no funciona amigo sigue sin encontrar el recurso solicitado

Comment: agrega tu código de la petición y quien recibe...

Comment: ok, edito la pregunta.

Comment: listo Albert Hidalgo

Comment: veo que mencionas que tienes un `iniciador.php` que es el que carga tus controladores, como funciona tu sistema ? tienes rutas `controller/action` o todas tus rutas son directas a archivos ?

Comment: si correcto Albert mis rutas son controller/action

Comment: Pues es de esta misma manera por la que debes acceder via AJAX por ejemplo `http://localhost/usuarios/user/1` no debes acceder por una ruta directa a un archivo.

Comment: gracias Albert voy a probar